# how can I speed up my sentiment analysis?

Tags: python, nlp, classification, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I'm doing sentiment analysis for several languages. my code runs successfully but it's extremely slow (10mn for just 11K records). Here is my code:

```
# Spanish Classifier - from https://github.com/aylliote/senti-py
clf = SentimentClassifier()

# Italian Classifier - Also for Russian
from polyglot.text import Text as T

# Germany Classifier
from textblob_de import TextBlobDE as TextBlob_d

# English
from textblob import TextBlob

# French
from textblob_fr import PatternTagger, PatternAnalyzer

def Flag(row):
    try:
        if row['lang'] == 'es':
            txt=clf.predict(row['rev'])
            return txt
        elif row['lang'] == 'it':
            txt=T(row['rev'])
            return txt.polarity
        elif row['lang'] == 'de':
            txt=TextBlob_d(row['rev'])
            return txt.sentiment
        elif row['lang'] == 'en':
            txt=TextBlob(row['rev'])
            return txt.sentiment.polarity
        elif row['lang'] == 'fr':
            txt=TextBlob(row['rev'], pos_tagger=PatternTagger(), 
            analyzer=PatternAnalyzer())
            return txt.sentiment[0]
        elif row['lang'] == 'ru':
            txt=T(row['rev'])
            return txt.polarity
        else:
            return ""
    except:
        return ""

df['sent']=df.apply(Flag,axis=1)
```

I've checked other posts about textblob.sentiments import NaiveBayesAnalyzer being very slow but I don't think it's the same situation i'm facing here?

Thank you

Comment: You can profile your code to understand what part is taking more time. Python's cProfile can be used for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks i will try that, i wasn't aware of that function

Comment: Hi, 
I checked one by one and it is the Spanish algo that's taking ages to run :

# Spanish Classifier - from https://github.com/aylliote/senti-py clf = SentimentClassifier()
if row['lang'] == 'es': txt=clf.predict(row['rev']) return txt

I'm not sure how i can speed it up..

Comment: Have you considered that this might be in fact because of the data that you're inputting into the spanish classifier? I.e. have you tried similarly long sentences of various languanges, or can you otherwise exclude a problematic dataset?

Comment: Hi, the sentences are very short, I think it's due to the algorithm. I will try to switch to using polyglot for Spanish sentiment and we can then compare.